# Store json data to php variable

Tags: php, json, decode

im trying to store data from a json file to php variables. But it wont work when i try to echo the variable for later use.

This is my json file:

```
"[{\"channelId\":150342342,\"channelName\":\"example.no\",\"channelUrl\":\"http:\/\/www.example.no\"},{\"channelId\":1529564329,\"channelName\":\"example2.no\",\"channelUrl\":\"http:\/\/www.example2.no\"},{\"channelId\":1536534822,\"channelName\":\"example3.no\",\"channelUrl\":\"http:\/\/www.example3.no\"}]"
```

This is my code:

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');

$channeljson = file_get_contents('channels.json');

$data = json_decode($channeljson, true);

$channelid = $data['channelId'];
$channelname = $data['channelName'];
$channelurl = $data['channelUrl'];
```

I have tried many other ways too..
Anyone have any tips that could work?

Comment: Your json file contains a string, not a JSON array. The issue probably resides in the part of your code where you store it, rather than where you use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file contains a json that represents a string, since it starts and finishes with the `"` character. Another issue are the escape characters `\`.

If you don't want to change de routine that writes the json files, you can solve your problem by correcting the invalid json:

```
$data = json_decode(trim(stripslashes($channeljson), '"'), true); // Removes the escape and the enclosing " characters
```

There is one more problem: the json represents an array of objects (arrays since you are passing true to the second json_decode function) and you are trying to access `$data` like a regular array.

See the $data contents:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["channelId"]=>
    int(150342342)
    ["channelName"]=>
    string(10) "example.no"
    ["channelUrl"]=>
    string(21) "http://www.example.no"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["channelId"]=>
    int(1529564329)
    ["channelName"]=>
    string(11) "example2.no"
    ["channelUrl"]=>
    string(22) "http://www.example2.no"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["channelId"]=>
    int(1536534822)
    ["channelName"]=>
    string(11) "example3.no"
    ["channelUrl"]=>
    string(22) "http://www.example3.no"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes it looks like you're right. The json file gets data from rest api. I may have to change the php file that write the data into json instead.